# How to pass the event interface?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following situation:

```
$('selector').live('click', openSite);
```

and open site takes the event like this

```
function openSite(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

If I change my first line of code to

```
$('selector').live('click', function(e){

});
```

How do I call siteOpen within this code correctly? openSite(e) does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you double checked your code for any typos? Here's a working example of how you've described your desired functionality.

http://jsbin.com/ijufe4

Comment: It sure can, but I was re-using the code example in the question to prove it can work in the method described, suggesting that perhaps a typo was to blame.